# How can I get the values from this file?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

How can I grep the values from this file?

```
[myfile.file]
documentation            My Documentation
test                     testvalue
test for my var          123
test_var2                this is my second var
test_bool                false
```

For example I want to get the value "123" for the key "test for my var" or the value "this is my second var" for the key "test_var2. Between the keys and the values (in the file) are a lot of spaces. In my bash variable I just want to have the value without these spaces.

My current approach is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(cat /tmp/myfile.file | grep '^test:' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Your approach is not working because you searched for a `:` which is not in the file.

Comment: What are your delimiters? Or is the file fixed width?

Comment: When I use '^test', I get all values back where the keys start with test.

Comment: Use the delimiter (`\t` or a fixed (?) amount of spaces) Paul Hodges asked you to specify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk` that splits fields on 2+ whitespaces:

```sh
awk -v s='test for my var' -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' '$1 == s {print $2}' file
123

awk -v s='test_var2' -F '[[:blank:]]{2,}' '$1 == s {print $2}' file
this is my second var
```

Comment: This works with gawk (GNU awk). My distro came with a different edition of awk. The same may apply to you.

Comment: There is nothing gnu specific. This worked on my mac (BSD) awk as well

Comment: Using the `{2,}` regex syntax in the FS did not work with `mawk` (Debian ships with it afaik now)

Comment: I don't have access to `mawk` but POSIX awk works fine with above pattern